# What should be triggered in a blog when deselecting a tag?

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, tags

I am writing a simple personal blog. The posts will have tags and I would like to give the reader the opportunity to choose, based on them, which posts are of interest to them.

To set the context, let's imagine two posts:

- "Something technical" with tags `tech` and `learn`
- "Learning methodologies" with the tag `learn`

The page opens with all posts, and a box with all tags set to "active" is provided on the top (with some explanation about the fact that one can click on them to filter the posts).

**Which behaviour is expected by users when they click on a tag (say, `learn`) to *deselect* it?**

1. since both posts carry the tag `learn` they both should dissapear?
2. since "Something technical" also carries `tech` it should stay (and "Learning methodologies" be hidden)?

I guess I am wondering whether I should go for the strategy *"remove articles solely focused on a tag"* (2. above) vs. *"remove anything which deals with a tag"* (1. above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you ask your (potential) users about their expectation? Seriously, that should be the UX-focussed approach.

Not knowing anything about the target user group, or the content, my general recommmendation would be to make it work like a filter: Keep all articles which have an active tag assigned.

So, if you uncheck "learn", the "tech" tag is still active, and the "Something Technical" article should be visible.

Comment: This is a personal blog and the potential users can be anyone. Though I agree with the idea of the filter approach.